# How to use topnav with left navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to follow the the guide below:
https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar

I want my layout to be the following:
[image: Desired layout]

where the black bar is a navigation that hides away using negative margins, the top bar grows in width when the left bar is hidden. The white space is for my content which goes into a container for bootstrap grid.

However current my layout like this:

[image: Current layout]

The blue bar flex's to the right but doesn't go to the top of the page

My HTML:

```
</head>  
    <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="skin-josh">    
            <nav id="sidebar">
                <div class="page-sidebar sidebar-nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        @if(isset($id))
                            @include('layouts._leftmenu')
                        @else
                            @include('layouts._leftmenu_noproject')
                        @endif
                    </li>
                </div>
            </nav>
    </header>



    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light" role="navigation">
        @if (session()->get('projectname'))
            <h3 style="float:left;color:white;padding-left:25px;">{{ session()->get('projectname') }}</h3>
        @endif  
        <div class="burgernav" style="float:left;height:65px;padding-left: 5px;">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" style="background-color:rgb(0, 131, 185);color:white;height:65px;">
            <i class="fas fa-bars fa-lg"></i>                
            </button>              
        </div>
    </nav>




    <body id="content">  
        @yield('content')
    </body>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
    min-height: 100vh;


    vertical-align : top;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -150px;
}

.sidebar {
    min-height: 92.58vh;/*100vh;*/
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
}
.left-side{
 width:150px;
    min-height:100vh;
}

.navbar {

    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: Could you make a codesandbox with all the dependency library set?

Comment: @AlvinTheodora https://fw3rx.codesandbox.io/ Here you go!

Comment: Maybe, you could attach the source code in codesandbox as well instead of the compiled version, so we can take a better look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the black div to have `position: fixed`, and then create a new div after the header wrapping all the div below it, with a margin-left equals to the width of the black div.
And dont need the `display: flex` in the `.wrapper` after that.

Comment: Thank you! Btw you can get the source from the compiled version of the codesandbox by https://codesandbox.io/s/[subdomain] so in this case https://codesandbox.io/s/fw3rx